# Substitution integral with $t=x^3$

Tags: integration, substitution

> $$
> \int \frac{3}{t(3+\sqrt[3]{t})} \mathrm{d} t . \text { Substitution } t=x^{3}
> $$
>
> $$
> \int \frac{3}{x^3(3+\sqrt[3]{x^3})}3x^2
>  $$
>   $$
> \int \frac{9}{x(3+{x})}
>  $$
>   $$
> 9\int \frac{1}{3x+{x^2}}
>  $$

---

Now i'm stuck

my calculation so far

Answer (score 3):

You could do partial fraction decomposition, but instead let's multiply the top and bottom by $\frac{1}{x^2}$:

$$3\int\frac{3}{3x+x^2}dx = 3\int \frac{\frac{3}{x^2}}{\frac{3}{x}+1}dx$$

Notice that the numerator is the derivative of the denominator times $-1$, so we have an integral of the form $\int\frac{du}{u}$, which integrates to

$$ -3\log\left(\frac{3}{x}+1\right)+C$$

Then substitute back in for $t$:

$$ -3\log\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{t}}+1\right)+C$$

Comment: $$
\text { Notice that the numerator is the derivative of the denominator times }-1
$$ could you show that for me?

Comment: @RackCloud try it yourself. If you get stuck, type up the work you have so far, but don't ask without trying.

Answer (score 2):

To finish your calculation:

$$\int\frac{9}{x(3+x)}$$

Take partial fractions

$$=3\int \frac{1}{x+3}dx+2\int\frac{1}{x}dx$$

Let $u=x+3,du=dx$ have

$$=3\int\frac{1}{u}du+2\int\frac{1}{x}dx$$

Then exists $C\in\mathbb{R},s.t.$

$$=3\ln(u)+2\ln(x)+C$$

Substitute $u$ back, we have

$$=3\ln(x+3)+2\ln(x)+C$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \frac{3}{t(3 + t^{1/3})} \, dt = \int \frac{1}{3 + t^{1/3}} \cdot 9t^{-1/3} \cdot \frac{1}{3} t^{-2/3} \, dt,$$ so with the substitution $$u = 3 + t^{1/3}, \quad du = \frac{1}{3} t^{-2/3} \, dt, \\ t^{-1/3} = \frac{1}{u-3},$$ we obtain $$\int \frac{3}{t(3+t^{1/3})} \, dt = \int \frac{1}{u} \cdot \frac{9}{u-3} \, du = 3 \int \left( \frac{1}{u-3} - \frac{1}{u} \right) \, du = 3 \log\left|\frac{t}{(3+t^{1/3})^3}\right| + C.$$